# Mysql Query to display records as it is using IN() in where clause and without any sorting

Tags: mysql

I need mysql query to display the order when i have subquery in it without any sorting
 Query which i am using

```
SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE AttributesID IN (SELECT AttributesID 
FROM processattributes WHERE ProcessID = 166)
```

result i am getting as below

```
 ID        NAME
 218       AA-Delays    
 219       AA-Internal 
 220       AA-External Errors
```

Am supposed to GET as below

```
ID  Name
219 AA-External Errors
220 AA-Internal 
218 AA-Delays
```

As sub query returns correctly `219 220 218` but final is not correctly please help out in the query

Comment: You don't specify an order so you can't influence the order.

Comment: IF i use ORDER BY FIELD(AttributesID,'220','219','218') I will get correct answer But these '220','219','218' are results from subquery  how to solve it

Comment: There is ambiguity for ID 219 in Actual result and Expected result, is it typo?

Answer (score 0):

The inner select does not return the data in a garantied way. So you have to define the order you want. You can join and then define the order like this (but I don't know on which column in the other table you want to sort)

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM attributes a
JOIN processattributes p on p.AttributesID = a.AttributesID 
WHERE p.ProcessID = 166
ORDER BY <some column in table processattributes>
```

Comment: the above query u have given results in                                                                     218 AA-Delays list
219 AA-Internal Errors integer
220 AA-External Errors integer.....  which is not the expected result

Comment: As I mentioned you have to define the order in the `order by` clause. Which column does give you the order you want? If you do not have a column that helps you with the order then you do not have a garanteed order.